# SQL - INSERT INTO only when the record does not exist

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I realize there a lot of answered SO question on this same topic, but I can't seem to use any of that information to figure out what's wrong with my query.

I'm trying to insert a record into my table only if a record with the same `database_owner` and `database_name` (those are two of my column names) does not already exist.

I'm using the query:

```
INSERT INTO users_databases (database_name, database_key, database_secret, database_owner) 
VALUES ('DB1', '263f690d-7ac3-49f2-aa3b-f5672e4639a2', '367123d8-e5a7-46a0-8101-21f39e6ac8d9', 'x@x.com') 
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT database_name FROM uses_databases WHERE database_name = 'DB1' AND database_owner = 'x@x.com');
```

But I'm getting the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.`

I should also point out that running the query

```
SELECT database_name 
FROM uses_databases 
WHERE database_name = 'DB1' AND database_owner = 'x@x.com'
```

does return a record.

Where could I be going wrong? From what I've read in the other questions, this looks correct. But it's obviously not. :-) Any advice would be super helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSERT INTO if not exists SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648934/insert-into-if-not-exists-sql-server)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288283/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists-best-practice

Comment: If you use a WHERE clause, then you must use SELECT instead of VALUES.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522379/atomic-upsert-in-sql-server-2005 for discussion as to why all the answers so far are wrong. If this is sql 2008, look at the `merge` statement.

Comment: @Brett, please mark the post that helped you as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is being marked as a duplicate, but the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648934/insert-into-if-not-exists-sql-server is much more complicated than the answer given here. This answer here wins hands down.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest solution would be something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT database_name FROM uses_databases WHERE database_name = 'DB1' AND database_owner = 'x@x.com')
    INSERT INTO users_databases (database_name, database_key, database_secret, database_owner) 
    VALUES ('DB1', '263f690d-7ac3-49f2-aa3b-f5672e4639a2', '367123d8-e5a7-46a0-8101-21f39e6ac8d9', 'x@x.com');
```

Comment: This did it! I guess I was trying the inverse. Thanks!

Comment: A good article to read on the fastest method for doing this [can be found here](http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/fastest-way-to-insert-new-records-where-one-doesnt-already-exist) if you're interested in speed or have several million records affected.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following, must work

```
  INSERT INTO users_databases (database_name, database_key, database_secret,    database_owner) 
  VALUES ('DB1', '263f690d-7ac3-49f2-aa3b-f5672e4639a2', '367123d8-e5a7-46a0-8101- 21f39e6ac8d9', 'x@x.com') 
  WHERE 1
        NOT IN 
       (SELECT 1 FROM uses_databases WHERE database_name = 'DB1' AND database_owner = 'x@x.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
INSERT INTO users_databases (database_name, database_key, database_secret, database_owner) 
SELECT 'DB1', '263f690d-7ac3-49f2-aa3b-f5672e4639a2', 
 '367123d8-e5a7-46a0-8101-21f39e6ac8d9', 'x@x.com'
 WHERE
   NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT database_name 
    FROM uses_databases 
     WHERE database_name = 'DB1' AND database_owner = 'x@x.com'
    )
```