# How to insert non duplicate names in SQL

Tags: sql, exists

I want to add a new user in my table users

```
users
------
ID  NAME
1   abc
2   cde
```

how could I use the syntax 'no exists' in this case if for example someone by mistake insert another user with the name 'abc' I dont want to enter with the same name user again.

Comment: If your names should be `UNIQUE` then put a unique constraint on the column. This will then ensure that someone cannot enter a duplicate value in that column.

Comment: In this case it would be better to use a unique constraint on the `NAME` field.

Comment: Probably this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288283/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists-best-practice

Comment: You can Make Name field UNIQUE, but when you are inserting records, call inserting function in try/catch block. because if user insert same Name it will through an Exception.. @Ronald Andrade

Comment: My table which has 10-15 million rows. If I put a unique constraint on 3-4 columns, will this be a problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make the column as `UNIQUE`

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE users ADD UNIQUE (NAME);
```

This will prevent to have duplicates in the column `NAME`

Comment: For some reason, I cant use that because I'm on Visual Studio 2010