# How can I insert into Table3 the intersection of Table1 and Table2, except the entries that already exist in Table3?

Tags: sql, sqlite, pdo, insert

First, to find the intersection of Table1 and Table2 I have

```
SELECT Id FROM Table1
INTERSECT
SELECT Id FROM Table2
```

or

```
SELECT Table1.Id
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id=Table2.Id
```

Now I want to insert that into table3:

```
INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT Table1.Id
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id=Table2.Id
```

But the problem is that some Id I am trying to insert can be already in Table3 (and Id is the primary key, so it must be unique).

I have read https://stackoverflow.com/a/5288322/1529630. Then, I have renamed Id to Id_ in Table3 to avoid conficts so that I can do

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM Table1 cr LEFT JOIN Table3 c ON cr.Id = c.Id_
WHERE c.Id_ IS NULL
```

But when I try to intersect...

```
SELECT Id FROM Table2

INTERSECT

SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM Queue cr LEFT JOIN Excluded c ON cr.Id = c.Id_
WHERE c.Id_ IS NULL
```

...I get an error. What I am doing wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is uniqueness of ids, try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table3(id)
    SELECT Table1.Id
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
         Table2
         ON Table1.Id=Table2.Id
    where Table1.Id not in (select Id from Table3);
```

EDIT:

I proposed the above because it seems the clearest way of expressing what you want.  The equivalent using `left outer join` might perform better:

```
INSERT INTO Table3(id)
    SELECT Table1.Id
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
         Table2
         ON Table1.Id=Table2.Id left outer join
         Table3
         on Table1.id = Table3.id
    where Table3.id is null
```

You can also use `INSERT OR IGNORE` to ignore the error:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Table3(id)
    SELECT Table1.Id
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
         Table2
         ON Table1.Id=Table2.Id;
```

Comment: But I have read that `select ... where col in ( select ... )` is so much slow, so I was trying to avoid it.