# INSERT VALUES WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK so I'm trying to improve my asp data entry page to ensure that the entry going into my data table is unique.

So in this table I have SoftwareName and SoftwareType. I'm trying to get it so if the entry page sends an insert query with parameters that match whats in the table (so same title and type) then an error is thrown up and the Data isn't entered.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblSoftwareTitles( 
            SoftwareName,  
            SoftwareSystemType) 
            VALUES(@SoftwareName,@SoftwareType) 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT SoftwareName 
            FROM tblSoftwareTitles 
            WHERE Softwarename = @SoftwareName 
            AND SoftwareType = @Softwaretype)
```

So this syntax works great for selecting columns from one table into another without duplicates being entered but doesn't seem to want to work with a parametrized insert query. Can anyone help me out with this?

Edit:

Here's the code I'm using in my ASP insert method

```
    private void ExecuteInsert(string name, string type)
{
    //Creates a new connection using the HWM string
    using (SqlConnection HWM = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStringHWM()))
    {
        //Creates a sql string with parameters
        string sql = " INSERT INTO tblSoftwareTitles( "
                   + " SoftwareName, " 
                   + " SoftwareSystemType) "
                   + " SELECT "
                   + " @SoftwareName, "
                   + " @SoftwareType "
                   + " WHERE   NOT EXISTS  "
                   + " ( SELECT  1 "
                   + " FROM tblSoftwareTitles "
                   + " WHERE Softwarename = @SoftwareName "
                   + " AND SoftwareSystemType = @Softwaretype); ";         

        //Opens the connection
        HWM.Open();
        try
        {
            //Creates a Sql command
            using (SqlCommand addSoftware = new SqlCommand{
                CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                Connection = HWM,
                CommandTimeout = 300,
                CommandText = sql})
            {
                //adds parameters to the Sql command
                addSoftware.Parameters.Add("@SoftwareName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = name;
                addSoftware.Parameters.Add("@SoftwareType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = type;
                //Executes the Sql
                addSoftware.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            Alert.Show("Software title saved!");
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use something like `INSERT INTO ... SELECT @P1, @P2 WHERE NOT EXISTS ...`

Comment: SQL2008+ : You could use `MERGE` statement [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: And how about using some constraints? Unique key?

Comment: Better way to do it to create a `UNIQUE` constraint. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.js Hmm I did try replacing the VALUES with a SELECT but its still trhowing up syntax errors.

Comment: @unlimit I don't think it'd work. You can have two instances of a software title but it can have two system types.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You could do this using an `IF` statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (   SELECT  1
        FROM    tblSoftwareTitles 
        WHERE   Softwarename = @SoftwareName 
        AND     SoftwareSystemType = @Softwaretype
    )
    BEGIN
        INSERT tblSoftwareTitles (SoftwareName, SoftwareSystemType) 
        VALUES (@SoftwareName, @SoftwareType) 
    END;
```

You could do it without `IF` using `SELECT`

```
INSERT  tblSoftwareTitles (SoftwareName, SoftwareSystemType) 
SELECT  @SoftwareName,@SoftwareType
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    tblSoftwareTitles 
            WHERE   Softwarename = @SoftwareName 
            AND     SoftwareSystemType = @Softwaretype
        );
```

Both methods are susceptible to a [race condition](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=race+condition), so while I would still use one of the above to insert, but you can safeguard duplicate inserts with a unique constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_tblSoftwareTitles_Softwarename_SoftwareSystemType
    ON tblSoftwareTitles (SoftwareName, SoftwareSystemType);
```

**[Example on SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64453)**

---

**ADDENDUM**

In SQL Server 2008 or later you can use `MERGE` with `HOLDLOCK` to remove the chance of a race condition (which is still not a substitute for a unique constraint).

```
MERGE tblSoftwareTitles WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
USING (VALUES (@SoftwareName, @SoftwareType)) AS s (SoftwareName, SoftwareSystemType) 
    ON s.Softwarename = t.SoftwareName 
    AND s.SoftwareSystemType = t.SoftwareSystemType
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (SoftwareName, SoftwareSystemType) 
    VALUES (s.SoftwareName, s.SoftwareSystemType);
```

**[Example of Merge on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64453/7)**

Comment: So is that like a composite constraint? Both of them have to be equal to throw up an error message?

Comment: I think I was using the wrong column name (`SoftwareType` instead of `SoftwareSystemType`), I've edited the answer and also added a link to example data.

Comment: OK so that is a nice website. Your code is great mate but I think its the fact that I'm trying to execute it through an asp page is the problem.

Comment: Looks like i may need to use a stored procedure

Comment: I see no reason why this wouldn't work through and asp page, even if the solution using `IF` doesn't work the other should. [Working demo on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c964/3), if you post the asp code it may provide an insight into why it is not working.

Comment: I've added an edit with the asp method, I can't see why it wouldn't work, your code would work great if it were just being used in the Management studio

Comment: Actually I'm a bell there's some other code that's throwing m e off in my application. Gareth you are a Don!

Comment: Its all working now mate, only issue now is my confirmation box which pops up if the sql executes regardless of data going in. Not the worst problem to have though!

Comment: To get around this, you can just check the value returned by `addSoftware.ExecuteNonQuery();`, if it is 0 then no insert took place, if it is one then the software was saved.

Comment: Yeah thought the same. Looks like i Have a bit more to do!

Comment: @GarethD: Are you sure the second method (i.e. the method without ``IF`` using ``SELECT``) is susceptible to a race condition?

Answer (score 10):

**This isn't an answer.** I just want to show that `IF NOT EXISTS(...) INSERT` method isn't safe. You have to execute first `Session #1` and then `Session #2`. After `v #2` you will see that without an `UNIQUE` index you could  get duplicate pairs `(SoftwareName,SoftwareSystemType)`. Delay from session #1 is used to give you enough time to execute the second script (session #2). You could reduce this delay.

**Session #1** (SSMS > New Query > F5 (Execute))

```
CREATE DATABASE DemoEXISTS;
GO
USE DemoEXISTS;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Software(
    SoftwareID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    SoftwareName NCHAR(400) NOT NULL,  
    SoftwareSystemType NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Software(SoftwareID,SoftwareName,SoftwareSystemType)
VALUES (1,'Dynamics AX 2009','ERP');
INSERT INTO dbo.Software(SoftwareID,SoftwareName,SoftwareSystemType)
VALUES (2,'Dynamics NAV 2009','SCM');
INSERT INTO dbo.Software(SoftwareID,SoftwareName,SoftwareSystemType)
VALUES (3,'Dynamics CRM 2011','CRM');
INSERT INTO dbo.Software(SoftwareID,SoftwareName,SoftwareSystemType)
VALUES (4,'Dynamics CRM 2013','CRM');
INSERT INTO dbo.Software(SoftwareID,SoftwareName,SoftwareSystemType)
VALUES (5,'Dynamics CRM 2015','CRM');
GO
/*
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_Software_SoftwareName_SoftareSystemType
ON dbo.Software(SoftwareName,SoftwareSystemType);
GO
*/

-- Session #1
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE  dbo.Software
    SET     SoftwareName='Dynamics CRM',
            SoftwareSystemType='CRM'    
    WHERE   SoftwareID=5;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15' -- 15 seconds delay; you have less than 15 seconds to switch SSMS window to session #2

    UPDATE  dbo.Software
    SET     SoftwareName='Dynamics AX',
            SoftwareSystemType='ERP'
    WHERE   SoftwareID=1;
COMMIT
--ROLLBACK
PRINT 'Session #1 results:';
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Software;
```

**Session #2** (SSMS > New Query > F5 (Execute))

```
USE DemoEXISTS;
GO
-- Session #2
DECLARE 
    @SoftwareName NVARCHAR(100),  
    @SoftwareSystemType NVARCHAR(50);
SELECT
    @SoftwareName=N'Dynamics AX',
    @SoftwareSystemType=N'ERP';

PRINT 'Session #2 results:';
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Software s
    WHERE s.SoftwareName=@SoftwareName 
    AND s.SoftwareSystemType=@SoftwareSystemType)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Session #2: INSERT';

    INSERT INTO dbo.Software(SoftwareID,SoftwareName,SoftwareSystemType)
    VALUES (6,@SoftwareName,@SoftwareSystemType);
END 
PRINT 'Session #2: FINISH';
SELECT  * 
FROM    dbo.Software;
```

Results:

```
Session #1 results:
SoftwareID  SoftwareName      SoftwareSystemType
----------- ----------------- ------------------
1           Dynamics AX       ERP
2           Dynamics NAV 2009 SCM
3           Dynamics CRM 2011 CRM
4           Dynamics CRM 2013 CRM
5           Dynamics CRM      CRM

Session #2 results:
Session #2: INSERT
Session #2: FINISH
SoftwareID  SoftwareName      SoftwareSystemType
----------- ----------------- ------------------
1           Dynamics AX       ERP <-- duplicate (row updated by session #1)
2           Dynamics NAV 2009 SCM
3           Dynamics CRM 2011 CRM
4           Dynamics CRM 2013 CRM
5           Dynamics CRM      CRM
6           Dynamics AX       ERP <-- duplicate (row inserted by session #2)
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at and its probably correct. This System is only ever going to have one user performing occasional queries. If he manages to open multiple sessions and try to do many inserts at once then it would be a problem but i don't think he will.

Answer (score 7):

There is a great solution for this problem ,You can use the Merge Keyword of Sql

```
Merge MyTargetTable hba
USING (SELECT Id = 8, Name = 'Product Listing Message') temp 
ON temp.Id = hba.Id
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
INSERT (Id, Name) VALUES (temp.Id, temp.Name);
```

You can check this before following, below is the sample

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.TargetTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.TargetTable
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TargetTable
    (
    Id   INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TargetTable PRIMARY KEY (Id)
    )
GO



INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (Name)
VALUES ('Unknown')
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (Name)
VALUES ('Mapping')
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (Name)
VALUES ('Update')
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (Name)
VALUES ('Message')
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (Name)
VALUES ('Switch')
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (Name)
VALUES ('Unmatched')
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (Name)
VALUES ('ProductMessage')
GO


Merge MyTargetTable hba
USING (SELECT Id = 8, Name = 'Listing Message') temp 
ON temp.Id = hba.Id
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
INSERT (Id, Name) VALUES (temp.Id, temp.Name);
```

Answer (score 5):

More of a comment link for suggested further reading...A really good blog article which benchmarks various ways of accomplishing this task [can be found here](http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/fastest-way-to-insert-new-records-where-one-doesnt-already-exist).

They use a few techniques: "Insert Where Not Exists", "Merge" statement, "Insert Except", and your typical "left join" to see which way is the fastest to accomplish this task.

The example code used for each technique is as follows (straight copy/paste from their page) :

```
INSERT INTO #table1 (Id, guidd, TimeAdded, ExtraData)
SELECT Id, guidd, TimeAdded, ExtraData
FROM #table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select Id, guidd From #table1 WHERE #table1.id = #table2.id)
-----------------------------------
MERGE #table1 as [Target]
USING  (select Id, guidd, TimeAdded, ExtraData from #table2) as [Source]
(id, guidd, TimeAdded, ExtraData)
    on [Target].id =[Source].id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, guidd, TimeAdded, ExtraData)
    VALUES ([Source].id, [Source].guidd, [Source].TimeAdded, [Source].ExtraData);
------------------------------
INSERT INTO #table1 (id, guidd, TimeAdded, ExtraData)
SELECT id, guidd, TimeAdded, ExtraData from #table2
EXCEPT
SELECT id, guidd, TimeAdded, ExtraData from #table1
------------------------------
INSERT INTO #table1 (id, guidd, TimeAdded, ExtraData)
SELECT #table2.id, #table2.guidd, #table2.TimeAdded, #table2.ExtraData
FROM #table2
LEFT JOIN #table1 on #table1.id = #table2.id
WHERE #table1.id is null
```

It's a good read for those who are looking for speed! On SQL 2014, the Insert-Except method turned out to be the fastest for 50 million or more records.

Comment: Love seeing the different approaches that can be used to resolve one issue. Thanks for posting the various snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but I found an original way to insert values into a table with the key words INSERT INTO and EXISTS.

I say original because I did not find it on the Internet.

Here it is :

```
INSERT INTO targetTable(c1,c2)
select value1,value2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from targetTable where c1=value1 and c2=value2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of set based operations using the ***EXCEPT*** operator, avoiding the complexity of writing a ***MERGE*** ex.

```
-- 1) Make a Temp table to hold new records to add
DECLARE @NewRecords TABLE(
    SoftwareID INT,
    SoftwareName varchar(125)
    )

INSERT INTO @NewRecords(SoftwareID, SoftwareName)
VALUES(10, 'Customer Validation'),
(11, 'Email Notification Tool'),
(12, 'IP Checker')


-- 2) Next CTE and Except operation to find set of records not in [MyTarget].[Table]
; WITH T AS
(
select SoftwareID, SoftwareName from @NewRecords
EXCEPT
select SoftwareID, SoftwareName from [MyTarget].[Table]
)
INSERT INTO [MyTarget].[Table]
Select SoftwareID, SoftwareName FROM T
```

Answer (score -2):

Ingnoring the duplicated unique constraint isn't a solution?

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tblSoftwareTitles...
```

Comment: question is tagged as SqlServer, not MySql, insert ignore does not exist in SqlServer.