# MySQL: How to replace a specific column with the other column from the other table

Tags: java

I'm trying to select all the records from columns in a table1
and replace 1 column with the other column from the other table...

it is possible?

```
select * from tbl1
replace tbl1.col1 with tbl2.col2
```

Comment: "Write code for me" requests are not acceptable here on StackOverflow. Break your task into smaller tasks, read the documentation for each of the components required, look for similar examples and try to understand how they work, write the code, and then if you have a specific question about it, come back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the adding an IF  or WHERE not exists to the INSERT statement
as described here might work:

[INSERT VALUES WHERE NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991479/insert-values-where-not-exists)

Comment: I cant understand... too isolated! im sorry. >.<