# Insert record if two values do not exist in MYSQL (same table)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a record into a table only if there is no existing record that contains two values. This query throws error:
"syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS"

I've tried various examples from SO posts but can't seem to get this going.

```
INSERT INTO tasks_admin2agent 
(trans_id,category,task_name,task_detail,date_due_d) 
VALUES 
('2186597-L1','Listing','Incomplete Listing Record', 'Please complete the 
listing record','2018-03-31') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT 
    trans_id,task_name 
    FROM tasks_admin2agent 
    WHERE trans_id = '2186597-L1' 
    AND task_name = 'Incomplete Listing Record'
    )
```

Comment: what is your MySQL version ?

Comment: MySQL version 5.0.12

Comment: I have added the answer you can check

Comment: Could you please accept one of the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it working from this example using FROM DUAL.

Thank you all for your assistance!

[How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql/3025332#3025332)

```
INSERT INTO `table` (value1, value2) 
SELECT 'stuff for value1', 'stuff for value2' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` 
      WHERE value1='stuff for value1' AND value2='stuff for value2') 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it works if you change "VALUES" to "SELECT". But I cannot explain why this works

```
INSERT INTO tasks_admin2agent 
(trans_id,category,task_name,task_detail,date_due_d) 
SELECT 
('2186597-L1','Listing','Incomplete Listing Record', 'Please complete the 
listing record','2018-03-31') FROM tasks_admin2agent
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT 
    trans_id,task_name 
    FROM tasks_admin2agent 
    WHERE trans_id = '2186597-L1' 
    AND task_name = 'Incomplete Listing Record'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not work for me. Throws sql syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tasks_admin2agent 
(trans_id,category,task_name,task_detail,date_due_d) 
SELECT 
'2186597-L1','Listing','Incomplete Listing Record', 'Please complete the 
listing record','2018-03-31' from tasks_admin2agent
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 
 *
FROM tasks_admin2agent 
WHERE trans_id = '2186597-L1' 
AND task_name = 'Incomplete Listing Record'
);
```

You can also look at:
[INSERT VALUES WHERE NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991479/insert-values-where-not-exists)

Comment: Tried this from the link you provided - but also throws syntax error.

IF NOT EXISTS 
    (   SELECT  1
        FROM      tasks_admin2agent 
        WHERE   trans_id = '2186597-L1' 
        AND         task_name = 'Incomplete Listing Record'
    )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tasks_admin2agent 
 (trans_id,category,task_name,task_detail,date_due_d)
        VALUES ('2186597-L1','Listing','Incomplete Listing Record', 'Please complete the listing record', '2018-03-31') 
    END;

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
INSERT INTO tasks_admin2agent 
(trans_id,category,task_name,task_detail,date_due_d) 
SELECT 
'2186597-L1','Listing','Incomplete Listing Record', 'Please complete the 
listing record','2018-03-31' FROM tasks_admin2agent
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT 
    *
    FROM tasks_admin2agent 
    WHERE trans_id = '2186597-L1' 
    AND task_name = 'Incomplete Listing Record'
    );
```

You can try [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gV8eo8daiy9RVbFpKWqWEp/0)

Answer (score 1):

Just set a (Composite-)Key-Constraint (unique) on the two columns in question:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD UNIQUE KEY `uniqueConstraint` (col1, col2);
```

Use a regular insert and "handle" "Duplicate Key Errors" -> That means the Value-Pair already exists.

This would also allow you to combine the query with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`-Syntax. (if required)

Note that aborted inserts or `On duplicate key update` will consume the next auto-increment id anyway.