# How do i check ID if it is already stored in database?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have this code that Inserts data to database. I want to check if the ID going to be inserted is already in database. but if it is not in database it should be inserted. But has some errors, can you please help me out with it?

```
    public void Add()
    {
        sc.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select idnum from TableVotersInfo Where idnum=@idnum", sc);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", _idnum);

            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rd.Read() == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
                rd.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableVotersInfo (Education, idnum, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, SchoolYear, ControlNum, VResult) VALUES (@ed, @idnum, @firstname, @middlename, @lastname, @schoolyear, @controlnum, 'Not Voted');", sc);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", _id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", _ed);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", _idnum);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", _firstname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", _middlename);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", _lastname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolyear", _schoolyear);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlnum", _controlnum);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Stored Successfully!");
                FAddVoters._cleardata = cleardata;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Edit**
My error now is `There is already an open DataReader associated with this command which must be closed first.`.

**Update**

```
    public void Update()
    {
        sc.Open();

        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE TableVotersInfo SET Education=@ed, idnum=@idnum, FirstName=@firstname, MiddleName=@middlename, LastName=@lastname, SchoolYear=@schoolyear, ControlNum=@controlnum WHERE id=@id", sc);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", _id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", _ed);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", _idnum);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", _firstname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", _middlename);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", _lastname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolyear", _schoolyear);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlnum", _controlnum);

            int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (res > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated!");
                FAddVoters._cleardata = cleardata;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer shows the "INSERT if not exists" best practice - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288283/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists-best-practice

Comment: just remove single quotations from idnum='@idnum' to be idnum=@idnum

Comment: i edited my code. sorry i messed up i thought i just copied the Add method. I did copied add and update method lol

Comment: after the if (rd.Read() == true), close the reader before executing it again.

Answer (score 2):

try remove single quotes in query like this

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select idnum from TableVotersInfo Where idnum=@idnum", sc);
```

and change type of variable `_idnum` from string to int

for solve error in insert try this code

```
public void Add()
{
    sc.Open();
    try
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select idnum from TableVotersInfo Where idnum=@idnum", sc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", _idnum);

        if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
        }
        else
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableVotersInfo (Education, idnum, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, SchoolYear, ControlNum, VResult) VALUES (@ed, @idnum, @firstname, @middlename, @lastname, @schoolyear, @controlnum, 'Not Voted');", sc);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", _id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", _ed);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", _idnum);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", _firstname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", _middlename);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", _lastname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolyear", _schoolyear);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlnum", _controlnum);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Stored Successfully!");
            FAddVoters._cleardata = cleardata;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        sc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: like this `int check = Convert.ToInt32(_idnum);` ? or?

Comment: now i have an error `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`

Comment: Has an error, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete oh,yes! forget del unused row `rd.Close();` see update

Answer (score 1):

Instead of two queries you could do it in one by changing `values` to a `select` and adding a `where` clause. After doing that you just need to check the returned value of `ExecuteNonQuery()` to see if `0` or `1` row was updated.

```
public void Add()
{
    sc.Open();
    try
    {
        using(cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO TableVotersInfo (Education, idnum, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, SchoolYear, ControlNum, VResult)
                                        SELECT @ed, @idnum, @firstname, @middlename, @lastname, @schoolyear, @controlnum, 'Not Voted' 
                                        WHERE @idNum NOT IN (SELECT idNum FROM TableVotersInfo);", sc))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", _id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", _ed);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", _idnum);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", _firstname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", _middlename);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", _lastname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolyear", _schoolyear);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlnum", _controlnum);

            var rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if(rowsAffected == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Stored Successfully!");
                FAddVoters._cleardata = cleardata;
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        sc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my post. Can you help me in my Update too? Coz if same thing happens, if idnum is already in database it just adds anyway.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete You did not do the same query as me, you need to learn the basics of SQL and you will understand what the difference between our two queries are.

Answer (score 0):

try **cmd.Dispose();** in ***else {}*** before again initializing the command object.
This should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Close the datareader object in `else`  also