# mysql insert if not exist without unique key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

As discussed in [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5289299/2037323  i'm trying to run following query from php and `$result = mysql_query($query, $con);` returns `true` but new records are not adding to `teamshalf` table. Whats wrong here?  http://pastebin.com/xCqWpKcb is data that i used for both tables.
One thing to mention here is that i can not use unique key here. So please tell if there is solution for non unique.

```
INSERT teamshalf
(`yearID` , `lgID` , `teamID` , `Half` , 
`divID` , `DivWin` , `Rank` , `G` , `W` , `L`)
 SELECT DISTINCT t1.`yearID` , t1.`lgID` , t1.`teamID` ,
 t1.`Half` , t1.`divID` , t1.`DivWin` , t1.`Rank` , t1.`G` , t1.`W` , t1.`L` 
 FROM `teamshalf_TEMP` t1 LEFT JOIN `teamshalf` t2 ON t1.`yearID` = t2.`yearID`
 AND t1.`lgID` = t2.`lgID` AND t1.`teamID` = t2.`teamID`
 AND t1.`Half` = t2.`Half` AND t1.`divID` = t2.`divID`
 AND t1.`DivWin` = t2.`DivWin` AND t1.`Rank` = t2.`Rank`
 AND t1.`G` = t2.`G` AND t1.`W` = t2.`W` AND t1.`L` = t2.`L`
 WHERE t1.`yearID` IS NULL AND t1.`lgID` IS NULL AND t1.`teamID` IS NULL
 AND t1.`Half` IS NULL AND t1.`divID` IS NULL AND t1.`DivWin` IS NULL
 AND t1.`Rank` IS NULL AND t1.`G` IS NULL AND t1.`W` IS NULL AND t1.`L` IS NULL
```

**SOLUTION**
As mentioned by @Arjan i was using `t1.col_name is null` instead of `t2.col_name is null`. So by modifying that i got desired result.

Comment: @Dagon, no, `INTO` is optional.

Comment: i changed to `INSERT INTO teamshalf` but still no new record entered to db. teamshalf_TEMP contain two different records, rest are same

Comment: ok, 'missing' optional but good idea `INTO` :)

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a name that is a reserved word, or you have embedded spaces or punctuation in them, and those are terrible practices to avoid anyway.

Comment: why is `yearID` a VARCHAR(2048) ? will it ever be anything but 4 numbers?

Comment: @AndyLester quote is because it is dynamically generated query and may contain columns with spaces.

Comment: @Dagon VARCHAR(2048) as it is loaded from csv and i don't know what that will be.Generated dynamically.

Comment: @TheRaaaZ I don't know what problem you are trying to solve, but loading data from csv files into dynamically generated tables without indexes and without proper column types, and then using those tables in queries, does not look like the proper way to me. Sure, it'll be fast with your small set of test data, but you don't want to try this with (tens of) thousands of rows in those tables.

Comment: Oooops..! I got stuck again. Working fine for small files but now when i tested with 8mb file, it continues loading. :( @Arjan can you please provide a suggestion? i'm dynamically from csv using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and comparing with above query

Comment: The solution is to use proper indexes. But if you only have dynamically generated tables it'll be hard to determine what a proper index would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is successful (otherwise `mysql_query()` would not return `true`) yet it does not insert any rows. The only explanation for that is that the `SELECT` part results in an empty set. That is because the `LEFT JOIN` returns rows that exist in `t1` but not in `t2`, but the select is done on `NULL` rows in `t1`.

This should work:

```
INSERT teamshalf
(`yearID` , `lgID` , `teamID` , `Half` , 
`divID` , `DivWin` , `Rank` , `G` , `W` , `L`)
 SELECT DISTINCT t1.`yearID` , t1.`lgID` , t1.`teamID` ,
 t1.`Half` , t1.`divID` , t1.`DivWin` , t1.`Rank` , t1.`G` , t1.`W` , t1.`L` 
 FROM `teamshalf_TEMP` t1 LEFT JOIN `teamshalf` t2 ON t1.`yearID` = t2.`yearID`
 AND t1.`lgID` = t2.`lgID` AND t1.`teamID` = t2.`teamID`
 AND t1.`Half` = t2.`Half` AND t1.`divID` = t2.`divID`
 AND t1.`DivWin` = t2.`DivWin` AND t1.`Rank` = t2.`Rank`
 AND t1.`G` = t2.`G` AND t1.`W` = t2.`W` AND t1.`L` = t2.`L`
 WHERE t2.`yearID` IS NULL
```

Also note that `mysql_query()` is deprecated. And you should declare columns that must contain data as `NOT NULL`, so `NULL` will not be accepted. And your query will be slow, because you're not using indexes.

Comment: thanks @arjan I got your point and now it is working. Thanks,solved a big problem. just for details, i'm updating question with working query.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should create a unique key by concatenating the fields that makes a record unique. (a record is never exactly the same as another record).
For example:

```
insert into table_a
(field1, field2, field3, field4)
select t_field1, t_field2, t_field3, t_field4
from temp_table 
where concatenate(t_field1, t_field2, t_field3, t_field4)
not in (select concatenate(field1, field2, field3, field4) from table_a)
```

I'm not sure what the equivelent of concatenate is in mysql but I hope you understand the explanation.

Comment: A primary key in MySQL can contain more than one column. And comparing function results is a bad idea because it cannot be indexed (at least in MySQL)