# SQL Server : updating one column and inserting if not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table `TableKats` that looks like this:

```
ID - int 
Name - varchar
KatID - int
```

What I want to do is to update the column `Name` from another table, and if there is a name in the other table that doesn't exist in `TableKats`, it should insert it and give `KatID` a 0

Does anybody know a way to do that? Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288283/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists-best-practice

Comment: So, for us to update a name we need to know that the name in `TableKats` is different from the one on the other table, right?, so, how do we know if we need to update it or insert it?

Comment: Yea thats ppart of the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using MERGE, as your other table schema is not known assuming Name as the column in other table too

```
MERGE TableKats T
USING ( SELECT * from TableB) AS S
ON T.Name = S.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( Name, KatID)
  VALUES ( S.Name, 0)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UDPATE  -- Not clear what needs to be updated.
```

Comment: It should just update the field if it exist, but that doens't matter anyway :) I actually also need it to delete rows in KatTable if the name doesn't exist in  the other table

Comment: @user3661240, you can do delete also using merge