# SQL Server insert if not exists best practice [EXTENDED]

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT `locality` (province_id)
SELECT DISTINCT `province_id`
FROM `locality` localreturn
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `locality` local
              WHERE localreturn.province_id = local.province_id)
```

**If the query tested passes how do i insert a value?**
 a normal insert would be like:

```
INSERT INTO `locality` (`province_id`) VALUES (1919)
```

Leeched Source:
[SQL Server insert if not exists best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288283/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists-best-practice)

Comment: What happens when you run the query?

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense. Basically you are trying to insert id's into a table where ids not present in that same table!! zero rows will be inserted with the first query

Comment: @Steve it just says it passed.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `locality` local WHERE  local.province_id=@id) 
    BEGIN
     INSERT `locality` (province_id) values(@id)
    END
  END
```

Comment: This answer is already present in the link given in the question!! Give some description about your answer that will help others. In the question he used only table(locality).