# Is there any way to restrict the data inserted into table if it is already present?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, tsql-sequence

I have an sp which when triggered, data will be inserted into the data table. If the data being inserted is already present in the table, I don't want the data to be inserted into the table. is there anyway i could use a logic to restrict the data into table.

my query is

```
declare @ident int =  IDENT_CURRENT( 'SADEV.RO_Transcript.ETQueueCtrl' )

insert into SADEV.RO_Transcript.ETQueueCtrl ([STU_ID],[STU_ORD_SEQ_NUM],[CreatedDate],[LastUpdatedDate],[ETQueueCtrlStatusCd],[ErrorFl])
select STU_ID
      ,STU_ORD_SEQ_NUM
      ,getdate()
      ,getdate()
      ,[ETQueueCtrlStatusCd] = 'N'
      ,'N'

from srdb_sr2_qa.dbo.SR0ROT rt
where STU_ORD_TYP_CD = 'A'
and ORD_DLVY_MTHD_CD = 'ET'
and STU_ORD_STAT_CD = 'C'

--and convert(varchar(1),STU_ORD_XPDT_FL) = @stu_ord_xpdt_fl
and case when @stu_ord_xpdt_fl = 'y' then GETDATE()
                            else case when ORD_PEND_INST_CD = '' then  STU_ORD_SBM_DT+ DATEADD (mi,480,STU_ORD_SBM_TM) 
                                    else  LAST_UPD_DT+ DATEADD (mi,480,LAST_UPD_TM) 
                                 end 
         end <= GETDATE()

select et.ETQueueCtrlID,
       ro.STU_ID,
       ro.STU_ORD_SEQ_NUM,
       ty.CAREER_CD,
       ty.CAREER_SUFX_CD


from SADEV.RO_Transcript.ETQueueCtrl et join srdb_sr2_qa.dbo.SR0ROT ro on et.STU_ID = ro.STU_ID 
                                                      and et.STU_ORD_SEQ_NUM = ro.STU_ORD_SEQ_NUM
                                   left join srdb_sr2_qa.dbo.SR0TYT ty on ro.STU_ID = ty.STU_ID
                                   where et.ETQueueCtrlID > @ident
```

Comment: Are you allowed to put a "Constraint" on the table, or are you looking for a different approach?

Comment: I am trying to go for a different approach

Comment: what is the unique key for the target table?

Comment: et.ETQueueCtrlID is the identity and unique key

Comment: in that where, can't you just include ETQueueCtrlID not in (select ETQueueCtrlID from SADEV.RO_Transcript.ETQueueCtrl)?

Comment: @sam assuming et.ETQueueCtrlID is not available, what combination of fields would we need to retrieve a unique row?

Comment: it shouln't satisfy the first select condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server insert if not exists best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288283/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists-best-practice)

Answer (score 1):

Could you add something like the below into the WHERE clause for the Insert?

```
AND 
NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM sadev.ro_transcript.etqueuectrl AS trg
    WHERE
        rt.stu_id = trg.stu_id
        AND
        rt.stu_ord_seq_num = trg.stu_ord_seq_num)
```

You can adjust the above to filter out those data columns that shouldn't be duplicated