# Copy data from one table to another iff second table doesn't already contains that data

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Could any one help me in writing a MS SQL query to copy rows from one table to another only if table1.Col1 != table2.col1.

I am making a SSIS package to do this procedure so an approach related to it would be very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server insert if not exists best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288283/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists-best-practice)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show your effort in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

1) [Slowly Changing Dimension](http://ssis-tutorial-online.blogspot.in/2013/06/ssis-scd-type1.html) data flow task.

2) Use [Lookup](http://azkhairuzzaman.blogspot.in/2015/09/ssis-perform-upsert-updateinsert-using.html).

3) Use [Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb510625.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way (to me):  optionally join (`LEFT OUTER JOIN`) to the target table (table you're loading into), and use `WHERE` to confirm that the join fails:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MYTARGETTABLE (TARG_COL1, TARG_COL2)
SELECT SRC.[SRC_COL1], SRC.[SRC_COL2]
FROM dbo.MYSOURCETABLE  SRC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MYTARGETTABLE  TARG
        ON TARG.[TARG_COL1] = SRC.[SRC_COL1]
WHERE SRC.[SRC_COL1] IS NOT NULL
----this column is only null if the join failed: 
AND TARG.[TARG_COL1] IS NULL
```

This of course assumes that there are no valid NULLs in the column(s) you join with.