# Excel and SQl Scripting

Tags: sql, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 2000 rows of data. I need to create a SQL script to insert the data into a table. Below is the formula I used in Excel and it works for creating the insert statement, but how do I "Not Insert" if `DiagnosisCode` already exists?

```
= "INSERT INTO CommonDiagnosis (DiagnosisCode, Description, ActiveThru, ActiveThruEnteredBy, DiagnosisFormat) VALUES('" & A3 & "', '" & B3 & "', '" & C3 & "', '" & D3 & "', '" & E3 & "')"
```

Comment: Instead of using the VALUES, use the SELECT [cell values] statement instead so you can include the WHERE DiagnosisCode NOT IN([cell value])

Comment: See this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288283/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists-best-practice

Comment: @ChaiXiong. Can you explain further? Maybe an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using an IF statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
 ( SELECT DiagnosisCode 
   FROM CommonDiagnosis
 )
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CommonDiagnosis (DiagnosisCode,Description,ActiveThru,ActiveThruEnteredBy,DiagnosisFormat)
VALUES ('"&A3&"','"&B3&"','"&C3&"','"&D3&"','"&E3&"')
END;
```