# SQL: Conditional Insert with order by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hi I have this [item about insert if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5288494) here. One of the things I want to know about is if I want to get the latest items from **CompResults** by using order by ResultDate, to be inserted to Competitors table, how should I do it?

```
INSERT Competitors (cName)
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM CompResults cr
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Competitors c
              WHERE cr.Name = c.cName) ORDER BY cr.ResultsDate DESC
```

An error happens: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: provide your table structure

Comment: 1st figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: 1) ORDER BY makes no sense when doing INSERT. 2) The error message says it all.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have to use order by fields in select statement I think You are using sql server
so You can use sub query

```
INSERT Competitors (cName)
select Name
from (
SELECT cr.Name,max(cr.ResultDate)
FROM CompResults cr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Competitors c
WHERE cr.Name = c.cName) group BY cr.name) as t order by ResultDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Row_Number` to get the latest record for each Item

```
Insert into Competitors(col1,col2..)
Select col1,col2,..
(
Select row_number()Over(partition by Name order by ResultDate desc) Rn, *
From CompResults  cr
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Competitors c
              WHERE cr.Name = c.cName)

) a
Where Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can as the below:

```
INSERT Competitors (cName)
SELECT
    A.Name
FROM
    CompResults A INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            CR.Name,
            MAX(CR.ResultsDate) MaxResultsDate
        FROM
            CompResults CR
     ) B ON A.Name = B.Name AND A.ResultsDate = B.MaxResultsDate
WHERE   
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Competitors c
              WHERE c.cName = A.Name)
```