# How to perform insert operation in SQL Server only when row does not exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table:# result
Name      Issues    Years      Value
Rani    Critical    2018        0.90
Rani    Critical    2018        0.00

Expected Output:-
Name      Issues    Year       Value
Rani    Critical    2018       0.90
Rani    Critical    2018       0.00
Rani        Null   2019        0.00


select Name=’Rani’,Issues=' Critical', years, ,Value from #result;

Insert #result (Name,years,Value) values(‘Rani’,year(getdate()),0)
```

I want to perform insert Operation on the #result table only when Current year(eg:-2019)
Is not exists.
If current year exists on #result table insert operation should not perform .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server insert if not exists best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288283/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists-best-practice). The question is for SQL Server but the answer is standard sql and applies here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IF NOT EXISTS to carry out this operation.

```
DECLARE @year INT = YEAR(GETDATE())
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #result WHERE Year = @year )
BEGIN
Insert #result (Name,years,Value) values(‘Rani’,@year,0)  
END
```

Comment: this isn't thread safe under default isolation level (and at any isolation level if not in a transaction)

Comment: @MartinSmith, if we are using temporary table, is there any issue. Can you please tell me, what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Good point, As it is a locally scoped temp table this is fine. No other session can be inserting rows to it

Comment: I don't think `GETDATE()` has any bearing in this question, although it's hard to tell from the question.

Comment: What's wrong with the solution in the question linked as duplicate of?

Comment: @MartinSmith, thanks. Yes. we have used temporary table in transactions without issues, as it is scoped to the session.